# Google Map not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have this simple app that will try to load a google map.  But when I click the link to view the map.  I got this error.

ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined
[Break On This Error]

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

Here are my codes

------------ scripts -------------

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBQ8OCC8En5vNHod25Ov3Qs5E1v7NPRSsg&sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var geocoder;

    //Show the google map
    function initialize() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("divMap"));

            map.setUIToDefault();
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        }
    }

    //Show default address on map
    function showTheMap() {
        document.getElementById('divMap').style.display = "block";
        initialize();
        var address = document.getElementById("spAddress1").innerHTML;
        geocoder.getLatLng(
            address,
            function (point) {
                if (!point) {
                    alert(address + " not found");
                }
                else {
                    map.setCenter(point, 15);
                    var marker = new GMarker(point);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                    marker.openInfoWindow(address);
                }
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

------------ HTML body ---------------

```
    <span id="spAddress1" runat="server" ClientIDMode ="Static"></span>
    <a onclick="showTheMap()" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Click here to view map </span>
    </a>

    <div id="divMap" style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 500px;top: -220px">
    </div>
```

thanks

Rjuy

Comment: What is `GBrowserIsCompatible` and where is it defined? Are you sure the javascript libraries are loaded before your code is run?

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091721/google-maps-api-javascript-error-when-gbrowseriscompatible-is-called

Comment: Are you using the Google Maps API v2 or v3?  The code posted is v2 syntax which is not compatible with the Google Maps API v3 (which is the tag you have used).  You didn't include the code that loads the API so we can't tell for sure (and if that isn't there, it is definitely a problem).

Comment: I am intent to use V3. from v2 i need to change the implemention to V3.  Updated the code thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the function `GBrowserIsCompatible()` if you haven't loaded the Google Maps API v2. You will need to obtain an API key to do so.

Incidentally, Google Maps API v2 is deprecated. Use v3. One advantage of v3: no API key required.

Comment: Hello, sorry to say, but this is not proper answer. I already try this method to do so, but still getting the same error. So can you please let me know the exact problem? My API Version is v3

Comment: You cannot use the function `GBrowserIsCompatible()` in API v3. It doesn't exist in API v3. It is an API v2 function. They got rid of it in API v3. You will have to rewrite your code to work in v3.