# Google map plugin not working with wordpress 3.8

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am using wordpress 3.8 CMS in which i am using google-maps-for-wordpress plugin but it is not working: 
Showing Errors in console:

```
ReferenceError: GBrowserIsCompatible is not defined
[Break On This Error]   

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
```

Please help me to solve this!
Thanks!

Comment: You'd be better off posting this on the plugin developer's support page

Comment: Also, have you made sure you've added the correct API key? Think I remember seeing that error a while ago, and it was solved when I checked the key.

Comment: @wickywills, How i can check that i am using correct API key or wrong ApI key.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API JavaScript error when GBrowserIsCompatible() is called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091721/google-maps-api-javascript-error-when-gbrowseriscompatible-is-called)

Comment: Is it this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-maps-for-wordpress/)?  It hasn't been updated since two years, use at your own risk.

Comment: @RRikesh yes it is plugin and is updated for wordpress 3.8 but not working

Comment: How can you say that it is updated for WordPress 3.8? On the plugin's page, it says `Compatible up to: 2.9.2`

Comment: @RRikesh sorry for for misunderstanding. Now i am using comprehensive google-map plugin 9.0.19 that is for wordpress 3.8. And this is still not working now showing console error: ReferenceError: CGMPGlobal is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

<script type='text/javascript'>CGMPGlobal.language = 'en';</script>

Comment: There's a problem with your API key

Comment: @RRikesh sir then what I have to do. Please suggest me.

Comment: Get a new key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a problem with your API key. You need to generate a new one by following the instructions provided [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)